# Exception : OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have published my app in play store. Now In Crashes and ANRs I am getting following errors on 2 devices (Galaxy Note3 and Galaxy Note II). I dont know how to solve these errors and what type of error is this? So please help me to fix these errors. On other devices I am not getting any report there.

Errors-

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3022)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1586)
at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16120)
at com.info.laughingbuddha.Buddha4.onCreateView(Buddha4.java:21)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1259)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Buddha4.java-

```
package com.info.laughingbuddha;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Buddha4 extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buddha, container, false);
    TextViewEx t = (TextViewEx) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t.setText("The Standing Happy Buddha brings riches and happiness.",true);
    t.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buddha4);
    return rootView;
    }
}
```

I dont know what code I need to post so If anyone require any code related to this please comment. Thanks.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Start by posting **Buddha4.java**. Anyway, it seems you're trying to load a **BIIIIIIIG image**.

Comment: I am getting report of 5 pages error in play store. All are same only difference in this line at com.info.laughingbuddha.Buddha4.onCreateView(Buddha4.java:21)

Comment: Only class names change i.e Buddha3, Buddha2 and in above one Buddha4.

Comment: @SanketKachhela I've edit my code. please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo I've edit my code. please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: It seems that **buddha4** is really a BIG IMAGE. If it's transparent (PNG), use OptiPNG to optimize it. If it's not transparent, make a JPG out of it. Anyway, here's a good [article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) from the android development team

Comment: @JohnR reduce resolution of that image and try to load.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo buddha4 png image size 640x720 and size 97kb.I think not big.

Comment: @SanketKachhela its resolution is 72.

Comment: Look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Comment: Can you post the XML code `R.layout.buddha`?

Answer (score 6):

Try to create scaled bitmap using following line of the code:

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, width,
                height, true);
```

Check the following links:

[android - out of memory exception when creating bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697760/android-out-of-memory-exception-when-creating-bitmap)

[Android out of memory exception with bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030542/android-out-of-memory-exception-with-bitmaps)

[Can I catch out of memory exception in Android in Bitmap allocation for decoding a picture file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666390/can-i-catch-out-of-memory-exception-in-android-in-bitmap-allocation-for-decoding)

Comment: I have to use some number instead of height and width in above code?

Comment: yes that you have to figure it out According to your device size and density. @JohnR

Comment: @JohnR did u find the solution?

Comment: Answer suggested by Andrew is right.  I am using all images in only drawable-mdpi folder. But the solution provided by him is not good as I want to scale images for large screens.

Comment: And the answer provided by you confusing for me as I am using weights in Xml. So dont know how to set height and width in equation provided by you. And For your solution I have to test my app again on all virtual devices.

Comment: I am using weight attribute in xml. So What width and height I have to use in code suggested by you? And Is it support all screen sizes?

Comment: see you have to get the width and height of the device by programatically then in that size what width and height you wat to set just put that thats all or you can use the desity

Comment: @JohnR you want me to give the sample?

Answer (score 2):

If you have high resolution image , you should scale them down to avoid different devices to load the image without facing a memory problem. 
In your case, some phones may not exhibit the same behavior on the first run, but eventually, without handling an optimized image loading solution, app will crash.

Check more on the "memory problem":

Topic under Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
[Out of memory error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620843/out-of-memory-error-android)

On how to avoid them:
[How to avoid an out of memory error while using bitmaps in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151719/how-to-avoid-out-of-memory-error-while-using-bitmap-in-android)

For an overview:
http://blogs.innovationm.com/android-out-of-memory-error-causes-solution-and-best-practices/
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Before setting a drawable as the background for your imageview, i.e.:

```
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buddha4);
```

as @rup35h  suggested in the answer, get a scaled bitmap or try other options like `inSampleSize`, do check how your solution affects the quality of your image too.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when we use so many images & backgrounds in applications, it takes lot of space on android RAM. 
This leads to force close your application by “Out of memory Bound Exception”.

It seems from your crash logs that you have drawable which is quite large, so to avoid the `OutOfMemory` you have keep drawables that would not take much memory. You can scale down the drawable either as some guys suggested in the answers.

If you don't want go through that and you have not much large size drawable then you can opt to increase your application heap size to large that would increase the heap memory.

> How to increase heap size

You can use `android:largeHeap="true"` in application tag of Android manifest(Reference here) to request a larger heap size, but this will not work on any pre 
Honeycomb devices.

On pre 2.3 devices, you can use the VMRuntime class, but this will not work on Gingerbread and above See below how to do it.

```
VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize(BIGGER_SIZE);
```

Before Setting HeapSize make sure that you have entered the appropriate size which will not affect other application or OS functionality.

Before settings just check how much size your app takes & then set the size just to fulfill your job. Dont use so much of memory otherwise other apps might affect.

### Update

Note : *It is always best practice to free the allocated memory of the bitmaps when these wont longer required, you can this `bitmap.recycle()`*

Comment: but why these errors not come on any other devices even those devices have old API versions. Why only on these 2 devices?

Comment: @JohnR This is not specifically for these, you might have same error on other devices also in future, there is no bug in your code but somewhat drawable taking more memory at runtime than available then Android OS opts in those devices to kill the application.

Comment: If I try largeHeap attribute in manifest file. Is it enough to solve this problem?

Comment: @JohnR Yes, most probably it will solve the issue, but please read my complete answer where I wrote what would be effect of this

Comment: I am using min version 8. So which solution I have to use. I am little confuse with your answer.

Comment: You can use `android:largeHeap="true"` if your targetVersionSDK is 11+

Comment: And for below levels?

Comment: I have covered all these in the answers, for below you can use `VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize(BIGGER_SIZE);`

Comment: I have one question In my app I am using min SDK version 8. android:largeHeap="true" is introduced from API level 11. So this code ignored by API level below 11 and work on API level above 11? Right?

Answer (score 1):

One problem I've had a couple of times is having a lot of MDPI drawable resources but no HDPI / XHDPI versions. When loading these on an HDPI or XHDPI device, Android will scale them up by loading the original, then making a a scaled up copy in memory, meaning you've got two copies in memory at once, the original and a scaled up version. If the drawable is being stretched by the renderer (e.g. If it's a background for a view), then there's no need for Android to scale it up when it's loaded, as the renderer does that anyway. So if you only have one MDPI copy of the image and don't want Android to scale it up, you should put it in the drawable-nodpi folder instead of the drawable or drawable-mdpi folders.

**EDIT:**

You can use the render time scaling available on an image view by setting the android:scaleType attribute. E.g. you could set the image view's width and height to match_parent, then set the scale type to centerCrop or centerInside to have the image scale up when it's drawn while maintaining its aspect ratio. centerCrop will totally fill the image view but potentially cut off some of the image, whereas centerInside ensures that the whole image is visible, but may leave some blank space. The scaling will be done at render time, so won't use any extra memory.

It can all be done in the layout XML like so:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

To have the image displayed fully inside the image view without cropping, change the last line to:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Finally, if you don't want to maintain the aspect ratio, you can use the following scale type:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: +1 for your great notice. I have all images in mdpi folder. I've never mention that here. I did not use any other drawable to make app size less.

Comment: I want images to be scaled. So any other option possible?

Comment: You can use the scaling available on an image view by setting the android:scaleType attribute. E.g. you could set the image view's width and height to match_parent, then set the scale type to centerCrop or centerInside to have the image scale up when it's drawn while maintaining its aspect ratio. centerCrop will totally fill the image view but potentially cut off some of the image, whereas centerInside ensures that the whole image is visible, but may leave some blank space. The scaling will be done at render time, so won't use any extra memory.

Comment: You deserve this bounty. But I accept your answer when you provide some code for your above comment.

Comment: It can all be done in the layout XML like so: android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: I do not want any part of the image to be cropped and please provide complete answer in your above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to scale down your image resource when loading it.

If you are loading the image, using a `Bitmap` variable, you can use the [`inSample`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) option, using [`BitmapFactory.Options`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html). Don't use the `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` as it will create another bitmap besides the original one!

Try the following code to load the bitmap:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; //This will just get the size of your image
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
//Get the downscale ratio
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, widthOfTheImageView, heightOfTheImageView);
//Decode the bitmap using the downsampled image
Bitmap finalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_name options);
//Finally, set the bitmap
imageView.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);
```

Where `widthOfTheImageView` and `heightOfTheImageView` represent the size of your `ImageView`.

The `calculateInSampleSize` method (I got it from the Android developers [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)):

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not load Bitmap directly if you are not sure about the size of the image. Sample it when the size is too large. At most time, the length of an image loaded should not exceed the length of your phone screen. Use code like this to sample image.

```
public static Bitmap loadImage(Context cx, Uri uri, int maxLength) {
    InputStream is = cx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Options opts = new Options();
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);
    int length = Math.max(opts.outWidth, opts.outHeight);
    int n = 1;
    while (length > maxLength) {
        maxLength /= 2;
        n ++;
    }
    is = cx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    opts.inPurgeable = true;
    opts.inDither = true;
    opts.inPurgeable = true;
    opts.inSampleSize = sample;
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);
    return bm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the views when you exit from an activity. Make it as `null` in OnDestroy().

if you are using Bitmaps

use

```
 bitmap.recycle();
```

when you used it.

you may use

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

in you manifest.xml to increase the heap size.